# How to find roots of function in Scala?

Tags: scala, equation, equation-solving

I'm writing a program in `Scala` and i want to find the roots of the equation: `2*x^3 + x*(1-2*l + 2*H)-m = 0`, where `l`, `H` and `m` are constants, calculated earlier.

In `Python`, i know there is `brentq` for such cases but i can't find anything similar in `Scala`. Is there anything similar or should try find other way of solving this?

Comment: In my opinion, your question is about doing something in scala, not in spark (unless you do not know how to perform the broadcast you are talking about). Therefore I would remove the apache-spark tag so that your question only appears in the relevant feeds ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's [spire](https://github.com/non/spire) which is a numeric library for Scala. I don't know it very well, but this seems to work in Spire 0.16.0:

```
scala> val m = 1
m: Int = 1

scala> val l = 2
l: Int = 2

scala> val H = 3
H: Int = 3

scala> import spire.implicits._
import spire.implicits._

scala> import spire.math.Number
import spire.math.Number

scala> val f = poly"2x^3 + ${1-2*l + 2*H}x - $m"
f: spire.math.Polynomial[spire.math.Rational] = (2x³ + 3x - 1)

scala> f.map(Number(_)).roots
res1: spire.math.poly.Roots[spire.math.Number] = Roots(0.3129084094792333580059444668826417)
```

Comment: This seems useful but i get an error in `f.map(Number(_)).roots`. I get `Cannot resolve method Number.apply`. I tried to figure out what's wrong but there are so little info about `Spire`.

Comment: Are you using the most recent (at least 0.16.0) version? Probably best to ask for help on their gitter channel, because this mapping to `Number` is probably not the recommended method anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any comprehensive math library in scala. There is one in Java though that you could call from your scala code.

You could have a look at Apache commons math and in particular at [section 4.3, root finding](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html).

Answer (score 0):

If `l`, `H` and `m` are constants then this is just

```
x^3 + ax + b = 0
```

Where

```
a = 1/2 - l + H
b = -m/2
```

There is a very hairy analytical solution to this, see Wolfram Alpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+%2B+ax+%2B+b+%3D+0

Expressing this in Scala is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 0):

As a previous solution commented, use Java's Commons Math! You just import the dependency and you can:

```
val polynomial: PolynomialFunction = new PolynomialFunction(Array[Double](-m, 1-2*l + 2*H, 2)
val laguerreSolver = new LaguerreSolver()
laguerreSolver.solve(100, polynomial, -100, 100)
```

This is way faster than spire.

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to look at Breeze, which I think would also have some routines to help you.